# UIProgressView not updating for Audio Player?

Tags: ios, ios10, nstimer, avaudioplayer

The ProgressView is not updating while playing the song. By reading from other post i have used an update method to update at each time interval.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Fix you_Coldplay" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Coldplay"];
NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[trackProgress setProgress:0.0];
}
```

I have a play button which is also being used for calling updateTime: method.

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
[musicPlayer play];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSTimeInterval interval = musicPlayer.currentTime/musicPlayer.duration;
NSLog(@"%f",interval);
}
```

The updateTime: method

```
-(void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
trackProgress.progress = (musicPlayer.currentTime/musicPlayer.duration);
}
```

I am very new to programming and even stack overflow. This is the first question i am posting. Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change timer value to:

//Change Value to 0.5 or 1 sec

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Make sure you are setting trackProgress as 0 as initial value.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    trackProgress.progress = 0.0;
   }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: This didn't work. When i am playing the Progress bar is moving from the zero position to little forward but after that then again its becoming stagant

Comment: Can you check what is the final float value you getting for this division : (musicPlayer.currentTime/musicPlayer.duration).

Comment: When i did insert a NSLog statement in updateTime: method, the float value is starting from 0.0 and the final float value is 0.999081. But at the end of the end track when i checked when the music stopped it was 0.002723, then suddenly jumped to 0.993965 and ended at 0.999081.

Comment: Can you give 1 sec timer and check because same code I am using for progressView Its working fine for me.

Comment: As insisted by you i tried with 0.5 and 1 second, but still no luck. The ViewController is not refreshing. Because the updateTime: method is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update the progress view on the main thread

```
-(void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.trackProgress.progress = (musicPlayer.currentTime/musicPlayer.duration);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help. Create a `Timer` and add it to `common runloop` as shown below. Also keep a reference to timer so that it can be stopped later.

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: *scheduled* timers are implicitly added to the run loop.